# Flutter BloC boolean updating state

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I'd like to realize a welcome screen for my application that is capable to change from Login to Register, with different forms and buttons, without changing some widgets on the screen (like the background for example).
I've tried to use the same scaffold with a stack, all sorrounded by a BlocProvider. The welcomeBloc should be responsible for the change of forms between login and register form. The loginBloc and registerBloc should be responsible for managing the state and inputs in the two forms.
The user repository is for operations like the login with google and so on.

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  LoginBloc _loginBloc;
  RegisterBloc _registerBloc;
  WelcomeBloc _welcomeBloc;
  UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loginBloc = LoginBloc(userRepository: _userRepository);
    _registerBloc = RegisterBloc(userRepository: _userRepository);
    _welcomeBloc = WelcomeBloc();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: _welcomeBloc,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Opacity(opacity: 0.6, child: Background()),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 130, left: 20),
              child: Text(
                "Welcome.",
                style: welcomeStyleBig,
              ),
            ),
            _welcomeBloc.getLogin
                ? BlocProvider(
                    bloc: _loginBloc,
                    child: LoginForm(
                      userRepository: _userRepository,
                    ),
                  )
                : BlocProvider(
                    bloc: _registerBloc,
                    child: RegisterForm(),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to implement the changing of form by using a boolean variable _isLogin in the WelcomeBloc but when I tap on the button responsible for the update, nothing appens until I hot reload the app. Maybe I didn't understand bloc pattern very well.

Here are my welcome bloc files.

welcome_bloc.dart

```
class WelcomeBloc extends Bloc<WelcomeEvent, WelcomeState> {
  @override
  WelcomeState get initialState => InitialWelcomeState();

  bool _isLogin = true;

  bool get getLogin => _isLogin;

  @override
  Stream<WelcomeState> mapEventToState(
    WelcomeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is SwitchToLogin) {
      _isLogin = true;
      yield WelcomeLogin();
    }
    if (event is SwitchToRegister) {
      _isLogin = false;
      yield WelcomeRegister();
    }
  }
}
```

welcome_event.dart

```
abstract class WelcomeEvent extends Equatable {
  WelcomeEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class SwitchToLogin extends WelcomeEvent {
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Switch to Login";
  }
}

class SwitchToRegister extends WelcomeEvent {
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Switch to Register";
  }
}
```

welcome_state.dart

```
abstract class WelcomeState extends Equatable {
  WelcomeState([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class InitialWelcomeState extends WelcomeState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WelcomeLogin extends WelcomeState {
  @override
  String toString() => 'Welcome Login';
}

class WelcomeRegister extends WelcomeState {
  @override
  String toString() => 'Welcome Register';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the widget state you need BlocBuilder not BlocProvider.

- BlocProvider provides a bloc to its children.
- BlocBuilder handles building the widget in response to new states.

Also you are using

```
BlocProvider(
   bloc: _loginBloc,
```

BlocProvider gets `builder:` as parameter not `bloc:'
I cannot understand how you don't get an error.

In you case you can do something like the code below.
(Probably there are many errors, but you can get the concept)

Also the documentation for [flutter_bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) library you are using is excellent.
I suggest you read it and also check at the examples

So i think the solution should be something like this:

```
BlocBuilder<WelcomeEvent, WelcomeState>(
  bloc: _welcomeBloc, // provide the local bloc instance
  builder: (context, state) {
    if(state is SwitchToLogin){
      return BlocProvider(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => _loginBloc,
          child: LoginForm(
            userRepository: _userRepository,
          ),
        );
    }
    else{
      return BlocProvider(
          builder: (BuildContext context) =>_registerBloc,
          child: RegisterForm(),
        );
    }
  }
);
```

hope it helps

Comment: This helps, but I had to wrap the two BlocProviders for registerBloc and loginBloc with another BlocProvider of welcomeBloc. If I don't do this the terminal says that I'm calling BlocProvider.of(context)<WelcomeBloc> (when I press the button for switching) on a context that doesn't have a welcomeBloc. Thanks.